# Using Ant to build project and run JUnit Test Android app but Ant Junit Test fails

Tags: android, ant, junit

I have a simple Android project that I created. I also created Junit cases for the project. I have my Android app and TestCases in the same project. My structure is like the following:

```
-AndroidApp
    -src
       -SampleActivity
    -tests
       -SampleActivityTest
```

I have changed the Order and export options and made sure JUnit is at the top.
I have added

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
android:targetPackage="com.sample.app"
android:label="UnitTest" />
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Running Android JUnit Test works fine in Eclipse, but when I try to build & Junit Test the app with Ant the project/app builds but the test fails.

Here's the error:

```
test-run:
       [junit] Test com.mark.prototype.test.SampleAndroidAppTest FAILED

compile-and-test:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

Can't figure out why it's failing in Ant.

Comment: If nothing else, ant -v (verbose) or ant -d (debug) might give you clues as to what is wrong.

Comment: What's the ant target you're invoking to run the tests?

Comment: @user1361551 Did you find any solution. Please let me know. I am also having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is create auto ant build via Export then select Ant BuildFiles and then modify it according to your requirement.