# Android test project fails to build under Ant, OK in Eclipse

Tags: android, ant, junit

I am trying to set up a CI build server for an Android app project and its JUnit test project.  I've generated the appropriate `build.xml` files for both app and test projects.

Both projects build and execute fine under Eclipse.

However, when I try to do `ant debug`  on the test project *without* having first built both projects with Eclipse, I get several `[javac]` errors saying `error: cannot find symbol` which refer to classes in the app project.

I **think** this is a difference between the classpath that Eclipse sees and the classpath that Ant is using...

How do I tell Ant where to find the app classes?

It seems the Android default `build.xml` defines all the targets, so I was wondering how to insert the appropriate reference in the app project's `build.xml`... rather than having to start the build file from scratch.

---

1. [Tried exporting the Ant build file from Eclipse; that fails to build either project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355363/using-ant-to-build-project-and-run-junit-test-android-app-but-ant-junit-test-fai?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to work is to re-run:

`android update test-project -m ../../app_project/  -p .`

within the test project.

The only change it made was to create an `ant.properties` file with one non-comment line:

`tested.project.dir=../../app_project/`

And now it all works swimmingly outside of Eclipse!